# Feed dialog, iframe display and callback

Tags: callback, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a problem with callback function using facebook feed dialog, it works ok when display param is default, but if I want to use display:'iframe' it does not fire at all. What could be the cause of this? Is this bug or proper behaviour? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I founde the answer....

When i'm using feed dialog with display param set to iframe and is set redirect_uri, feed dialog does not fire any callback. But it works fine if is set a default display value.

The workaround in case of display:iframe is very simple, we just don't use redirect_uri param and redirect user in callback function. But there is no info about this in official documentation

Comment: Thank You, this is the the only thing that solved my problem after hours of digging everywhere